# How to animate text dependent on other element while maintaining absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, opacity

I'm trying to implement a fairly simple animation where a title and a `div` move upwards on hover. The problem is the `div` has a transparency setting which means the title had to placed outside of it to not be dependent on the opacity. So now the title is not moving along with the box. Should I group the elements or change the HTML/CSS structure?

**HTML:**

```
<a class="gbox a2" href="#">
    <div></div>
    <h2>TITLE</h2>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.gbox       {border:1px solid #aaa; position:relative;}
.gbox div   {background:#ddd; opacity:0.75; height:80px; position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%}
.gbox h2    {position:absolute; right:20px; bottom:12px; color:#000}
.a2         {width:338px; height:194px; background:#333; display:inline-block}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.gbox').hover(
    function() { $(this).children('div').animate({height: '+=10px'}, 200) },
    function() { $(this).children('div').animate({height: '-=10px'}, 200) }
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YS2s9/

Comment: Based on the HTML here, could you not just use an `rgba` background colour on the `div`, and thus place the `h2` inside the `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an instance where you'd specifically want to select only `div`'s in your animation? Would this modification to your script yield the desired result?

```
$('.gbox').hover(
    function() { $(this).children().animate({height: '+=10px'}, 200) },
    function() { $(this).children().animate({height: '-=10px'}, 200) }
);
```

Comment: So grouping is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: In this instance, yes it would be the most appropriate way to go ;)